# How to implement a simple event queue?

Tags: c++, events

So, I did a reasonable amount of googling first, but all of the solutions seem unreasonably complex.  So, I thought I'd ask here to see if this task really requires the kind of approach I've been encountering...

So, say I have an `Event` class.  I would like it to have a `time` variable, and a `functionToExecuteAtTime` function pointer / variable / magic piece of code that lets me pass any old function to this class.

Also I would like the events held in a priority queue that arranges the events in order of time and executes the functions they are "carrying".  But **forget about this for now**

Something like this...

```
class Agent
{
    public:

    int id;
    float cash;

    Agent::Agent
    {
        cash = 100;
    }
}

class uberSystem
{
    public:

    float assets;
    int supplyOfDeadlyPoison;
    float poisonCost;

    std::vector<Agent> agents;

    uberSystem::uberSystem
    {
        assets = 100000;
        supplyOfDeadlyPoison = 100000;
        poisonCost = 8;

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
        Agent newAgent;
        newAgent.id = i;
        agents.push_back(newAgent)
        }
     }
};


class Event
{
    public:

    int time;
    SOMETHING_THAT_LETS_ME_HOLD_FUNCTIONS myFunction;

    Event::Event(int t, SOMETHING_THAT_LETS_ME_HOLD_FUNCTIONS func)
    {
         time = t;
         myFunction = func;
    }
}

int uselessFunction()
{
    return 42;
}

void buyPoisonAndKillAgent(Agent &myAgent, uberSystem &mySystem)//obviously not good...
{
    myAgent.cash -= mySystem.poisonCost;
    mySystem.assets += mySystem.poisonCost;
    mySystem.agents.erase(mySystem.agents.begin()+myAgent.id);
    mySystem.supplyOfDeadlyPoison -= 1;
}


int main()
{

    uberSystem newSystem;
   // Event newEvent(100, uselessFunction());//make a new event
    Event newEvent(100, buyPoisonAndKillAgent(newSystem.agents[5], newSystem));
    newEvent.myFunction;//run the bloody function
    return 0;
}
```

Okay, so that looks like extremely wishful thinking now that I type it.  So, how can I achieve this?  Is function pointers the way to go?  Or is there some better way that I have somehow managed to not find yet?

Oh, and apparently I do have `std::function` available after all... I was not in the stone age all along!

Thanks!

Comment: What about [std::deque<std::shared_ptr<Event>>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque)?

Comment: std::function can do it, i suggest you to avoid function pointers. :)

Comment: Is the "time" real time or simulated? Or is it just used to order the events?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, std::function is c++11, which I really should have upgraded to by now... :-)  Oh, and time is just used for ordering...

Comment: Ohh sorry, i missed that part. However C++11 is really cool, it makes things so much simpler! :) (so for example you could use lambdas for this) For now it seems like in C++03 Ed Heal's solution can be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a Base class Event (as proposed by @EdHeal) and then have a templated subclass storing your function pointer:

```
class Event {
public:
  int time;
  Event(int t) : time(t) {}
  virtual ~Event(){}
  virtual void myFunction() = 0;
};

template<typename TFunc>
class TEvent : public Event {
public:
  TFunc func;
  TEvent(int t, TFunc f) : Event(t), func(f) {} 
  void myFunction() { func(); }
};

template<typename TFunc>
auto_ptr<Event> make_event(int time, TFunc func) {
    return std::auto_ptr<Event>(new TEvent<TFunc>(time,func));
}
```

With the helper function `make_event` it is easy to call and deduces the type automatically:

```
void useless() {std::cout << "Func A";}
struct functor {
  void operator()() {std::cout << "Functor B";} 
};

struct paramFunctor {
  paramFunctor(int x, double y): result(0), m_x(x), m_y(y){}

  void operator()() {
    std::cout << "Params: x:" << m_x << ", y:" << m_y << "\n";
  } 
  long long result;
private:
  int m_x;
  double m_y;
};

int main() {
  auto_ptr<Event> e1 = make_event(10,useless);
  auto_ptr<Event> e2 = make_event(100,functor());
  auto_ptr<Event> e2 = make_event(100,paramFunctor(1,2.0));

  // your code goes here

  e1->myFunction();
  e2->myFunction();
  e3->myFunction();

  return 0;
}
```

Of course, if there is access to C++11 (or TR1, or boost) there is no need for all this at all (as other answers describe)

Comment: @MatthieuM. I would, but the question asked for the stoneage - preC++11 solution ;)

Comment: So? `std::auto_ptr` and `boost::scoped_ptr` are perfectly compatible with C++03. `boost::shared_ptr` worked there as well. Only `std::unique_ptr` was made possible by C++11 new features (move semantics, specifically).

Comment: Well I guess it doesn't hurt to use auto_ptr. On the other hand, if there is access to boost (or TR1), then there there is no need for all this at all, and you can simply store the function object.

Comment: Yes, I think `boost::function` might be the easiest (as long as you only need one function); your solution however offers a bit more flexibility (it's easier to add another virtual method).

Comment: Well...I don't mean to seem ungrateful but....it doesn't really seem very versatile, unless I'm missing something (not just this answer - in fact this one is probably the best).  I mean, what if I want to pass variables to the function(s).  Of unknown type and number?

Comment: @user3146160 This depends on what you expect. If you want to call `Event::myFunction()` with an unknown list of parameters and return types, this will be difficult. The compiler cannot know which function is stored internally. If you know all parameters at time of creating your event, you can store them into a functor and use them later (I add an example for a functor with parameters). If you need different return types, it gets more tricky. You will have to change `TEvent` to store a reference to your functor, and read the result from the function object instead of the event.

Comment: Well, to begin with I was kind of hoping for something like my example...but with the ability to throw about fifty billion random functions with millions of different variables and hundreds of thousands of return types at it and they all just go pop! done!  Guess not, huh?  Oh well, thanks for the updated code...

Comment: @user3146160 could you add some calling examples to your question? I'm not sure if i can follow correctly

Comment: okay so that's changed now.  Pretty crappy...basically I would like a system with agents, and the functions to act on different variables of the system and the agents in it in all kinds of interesting ways or something like that.

Comment: @user3146160 This should be possible. Have a look at `paramFunctor`, and imagine x being myAgent, and y being mySystem. within `void operator()` you can callever whatever you want, like `buyPoisonAndKillAgent(agent,system)` with parameters stored in your functor.

Comment: Hmm.  I guess I could just change the ints/floats to a typedef of some sort, and then just pass it the address of whatever variable I'm trying to change...?  Thanks for all your help anyway, SO is asking if it wants me to move this to "chat" or something so I guess it's time for me to do my own research now...

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this

```
class Event {
    private:
       int time;
    public:
       Event(int t) : time(t)  { }
       virtual void DoEvent() = 0;
};

class MyEVent: public Event {
    public:
        MyEvent(int t) : Event(t) { }
        void DoEvent() { std::cout << "Event  called" << std::endl;
};
```

then

```
int main() {

    MyEvent e(100);
    e.DoEvent();
    return 0;
}
```

This seems simpler and you have the luxury of adding whatever data is required for the event.

For a list you use `Event` pointers e.g. `Event *e = new MyEvent(100)`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to hold a generic function or closure is to use `std::function`; in the absence of C++11 [`boost::function`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/function.html) is a good placeholder for it.

This yields:

```
class Event {
public:
private:
    std::time_t time;
    boost::function<void()> function;
}; // class Event
```

Note that the signature of the function need be precised: `void()` is a function taking no argument and returning nothing.

Also, note that you can arbitrary predicates, functor classes or lambdas, as long as one of the `operator()` matches the expected signature.