# c++ Event queues, variadic functions, static functions and other strange stuff

Tags: c++, c++11, static, variadic-templates

after yesterday's rip-roaring thread at [How to implement a simple event queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175588/how-to-implement-a-simple-event-queue) , I decided to finally make the big leap to c++11.  Just before c++14 comes out probably...

Anyway, it occured to me that variadic functions are the perfect way forward in this enjoyable endeavour.  They probably aren't really, but anyway, I managed to steal and bastardize some code I found somewhere, and ended up with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <queue>

class Event
{
public:
    int timeOfCompletion;
    std::function<void()> function;
    inline bool operator<(const Event& target) const
    {
        return target.timeOfCompletion < timeOfCompletion;
    }
};

class System
{
public:

    int someValue;
    std::priority_queue<Event> funcs;

    System()
    {
        someValue = 100;
    }

    template<typename Func, typename...Args>
    void addFunctionToQueue(const int t , const Func&& myFunc, Args&&... myArgs)
    {
        Event newEvent;
        std::function<void()> func = std::bind( std::forward<Func>(myFunc), std::ref(myArgs)...);
        newEvent.function = func;
        newEvent.timeOfCompletion = t;
        funcs.push(newEvent);
    }

    void runAllFunctions()
    {
        while(!funcs.empty())
        {
            Event func = funcs.top();
            funcs.pop();
            func.function();
        }
    }

    static void doStaticFunction(int a)
    {
        std::cout <<"I would like to change someValue here, but can't :-(\n";
        //someValue -= a;//invalid
    }

    void doNonStaticFunction(int a)
    {
        someValue -= a;
        std::cout <<"Set someValue to " << someValue << "\n";
    }

};

int main()
{
    System newSystem;

    newSystem.doNonStaticFunction(5);

    newSystem.addFunctionToQueue(5, System::doStaticFunction, 1);
    newSystem.runAllFunctions();

    //newSystem.addFunctionToQueue(5, newSystem.doStaticFunction, 1);// is invalid
    //newSystem.addFunctionToQueue(5, System::doNonStaticFunction, 1);// is invalid
    //newSystem.addFunctionToQueue(5, newSystem.doNonStaticFunction, 1);// is invalid
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Anyhow, how can I get the "addFunctionToQueue" function to work with non-static functions?  I thought I had more questions, but I think if I can get that one answered, my other problems will hopefully be solved...

Comment: To format code, paste the code in the edit box, select it and press Ctrl-K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove a `const` qualifier from the `Func` parameter.

   ```
   template<typename Func, typename...Args>
   void addFunctionToQueue(int t , Func&& myFunc, Args&&... myArgs)
   //                              ~~~^ no const
   ```

*Rationale:* When using a *forwarding reference* (or an lvalue reference) type with a template argument deduction, a `const` qualifier is automatically deduced (depending on the argument's qualifiers). Giving it explicitly prevents the compiler from adding it to the `Func` type itself, which results in an error when you try to `std::forward<Func>`. That said,  you would need to write `std::forward<const Func>` instead to avoid the compiler error, but still, that would make no sense, as `const T&&` is not a *forwarding reference*.

2. Non-static member functions require an object for which they will be called, just like you write `a.foo()`, not `foo()`.

   ```
   newSystem.addFunctionToQueue(5, &System::doNonStaticFunction, &newSystem, 1);
   //                                                            ~~~~~~~~~^ context
   ```

Comment: Also, `const Func&&` is an rvalue reference, not a forwarding reference (Herb Sutter's new name for universal reference). It doesn't bind to lvalues.